# Downloading a file with BrowserKit/Mink

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

### Preface

Using Behat, I can write a scenario like this:

```
  Scenario: I can get a template
    When I send a GET request to "/products/template"
    Then the response status code should be 200
```

that links to this Behatch step implemented by `vendor/behatch/contexts/src/Context/RestContext.php`:

```
 /**
     * Sends a HTTP request
     *
     * @Given I send a :method request to :url
     */
    public function iSendARequestTo($method, $url, PyStringNode $body = null, $files = [])
    {
        return $this->request->send(
            $method,
            $this->locatePath($url),
            [],
            $files,
            $body !== null ? $body->getRaw() : null
        );
    }
```

### Request

In order to validate file responses, I would like to write a scenario like:

```
  Scenario: I can get a template
    When I send a GET download request to "/products/template" and save it to "/tmp"
    Then the response status code should be 200
    And the file "/tmp/template.csv" should exist
```

I would like to write a step that sends a GET request and downloads a file to a provided path, akin to the [sink Guzzle functionality](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#sink), similar to:

```
/**
 * Sends a HTTP request
 *
 * @Given I send a :method download request to :url and save it to :path
 */
public function iSendADownloadRequestTo($method, $url, $path)
{

    return $this->request->send(
        $method,
        $this->locatePath($url),
        ["sink" => __DIR__.$path]
    );
}
```

The previous code succesfully sends the request but it doesn't save the file. How could I achieve this?

Comment: I think to bend Mink to do this will be pretty tough, if not somewhere near impossible. Any issue with using Guzzle for this (or plain old curl for that matter)? I think you could test the same functionality with it.

Comment: Use Guzzle for all rest api tests and define steps as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I would download the file with use of `Guzzle` or `curl`. `Mink` is used and designed to interact with pages, and to my knowledge and quick glance at its docs doesn't support functionality you are after.